# What to use for Reactjs drag drop and resize feature on all device?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resizable, react-dnd

I am trying to achieve drag, drop and resize feature in reactjs that should work on all devices and should support mouse and touch. I have developed drag and drop for mouse and touch using ReactDND and it works fine. Trying to achieve Resize feature using react-resizable. Here is a description of the functionality.

**Description :**  I am trying to develop UI for managing appointments. UI draws calendar week, each column represents day and each row represents time in a day i.e. 30 minutes. there are list of items user can drag and drop on these cells and schedule an appointment for themselves. each appointment currently sets for 30 minutes because of cell represents 30 minutes. Since appointment can go over 30 minute, I want to add resize feature so that user can easily drag bottom right corner and can resize it to schedule that appoint for more than 30 mins. I have used ReactDND for drag drop on all devices and to support mouse and touch. to resize the appointment I am trying it using react-resizable and trying to find the cell on which resize ends using X & Y position since there is no direct way of finding the cell on which resize has ended.

I am asking this question to know whether am I moving in right direction or is there a better way to solve this issue or any better library which I can use that saves me time and effort.

Would appreciate your help and support in this. Thanks :)